# Should I mention chess performance as strategic planning skills in my CV?

Tags: resume, skills

Since my past works didn't require strategic planning skills much, I think than mentioning about my chess skills is a good example for it. What do you think?

Here is my draft:

> ## Skills
>
> **Strategic planning:** top 50 players in Chess Tournament for Students in City X (2012)

Comment: Top 50 in city not.  Top in state yes.

Comment: @Paparazzi i'm living in a country where the largest unit of the country is city

Comment: Aside from the other issues here, you're dragging up a *student* chess tournament from *four years ago*? It's time to let it go man.

Comment: Is there any reason to expect a correlation between chess skill and business strategic planning skill? [Bobby Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Fischer) excelled at chess, but some of his out-of-game actions were arguably not very well chosen and planned.

Comment: No, I wouldn't argue playing chess demonstrated strategic planning skills, due to the reasons outlined in @Nij's answer. I would encourage you to visit chess.se regarding becoming better at playing :-)

Comment: Only mention your mad chess skills if you're an IM or GM.

Comment: As a chess player I can say that your skills section tells absolutely nothing. Top 50 of how many? Out of 50, 51, or 10k people. How good are other people? I can win a first place competing with 10k people who barely learned how to move pieces. Your section does not show anything about your skill as a player and it is similar to 'a marathon runner sticker' that people who can't brag about anything else use to boost their self-esteem. Everyone can be a marathon runner: you just need to come and do a few moves. Everyone can even finish a marathon (some might need a week, but they still finished)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan is there any reason to believe that a diploma from a university has any correlation with strategic planning? There are computer programs that have not finished even preschool and which perform better in strategic planning than almost every human.

Comment: @SalvadorDali but did those computers programming themselves? No - they are just blindly crunching numbers the way they were told they should, when a group of *humans* set them up that way.

Comment: @Nij not sure about those specific computer programs, but a lot of AI systems nowadays are actually learning by themselves. Some group of people clearly write programs and then they learn. About crunching numbers: why do you think that your brain are not crunching synaptic connections to write messages. And why is crunching numbers so fundamentally different? Back to the topic: **the only strong correlation for a strategic planning is how an individual can do strategic planning**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strategies in chess boil down to memorising a set of patterns and using them in combinations against the set of patterns your opponent has memorised and combined, then hope they make at least one more mistake than you.

Strategic planning in a business is much more complex:

- you don't have perfect and open and freely accessible information of the game state
- the game is not remotely zero-sum
- the rules are dynamic and with significant regional variation
- you are not in sole charge of your resources or choice of plan
- you are not seeking an endgame, but an open-ended improvement process

Each of these alone makes your chess experience not a brilliant starting point for business strategy planning. At best it will help when you begin learning, but there are other skills which would be far more important in a business setting, like the ability to manage time pressure or to self-develop your skillset for a task.

TLDR: don't bother.

Comment: I would actually say that all these variables make the decision less complex, as thinking ahead many steps is never going to work anyway, so why do it.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Business strategy is to think ahead a few steps, such that each time you are optimised for any potential outcome (much more like backgammon, really). Chess strategy is to think ahead a large number of steps, such that each time you are optimised for one or two (perhaps, if you're brilliant, three) of the potential outcomes, and that is only possible because there are so few choices to make at each step, and an even smaller subset of them are remotely beneficial. The decision is not made easier by the fact that even more decision**s** must also be made.

Comment: I would also assume that there is no correlation between chess strategy and strategy required in most "real life" activities. Of course, I don't have proof, but the thought seems ridiculous to me.

Comment: Excellent on **business strategy is to think ahead a few steps, such that each time you are optimised for any potential outcome. Chess strategy is to think ahead a large number of steps, such that each time you are optimised for one or two of the potential outcomes, and that is only possible because there are so few choices to make at each step**

Answer (score 9):

> Since my past works didn't require strategic planning skills much, I
>   think than mentioning about my chess skills is a good example for it.
>   What do you think?

Unless you are planning to apply for a job as a chess tutor, then leave off your chess skills. The same would be true for other games - backgammon, bridge, poker, etc.

Your resume should reflect your abilities relevant to the job for which you are applying. While chess involves strategy, jobs in business requiring "strategic planning skills" are looking for something different.

> Strategic planning is an organizational management activity that is
>   used to set priorities, focus energy and resources, strengthen
>   operations, ensure that employees and other stakeholders are working
>   toward common goals, establish agreement around intended
>   outcomes/results, and assess and adjust the organization's direction
>   in response to a changing environment. It is a disciplined effort that
>   produces fundamental decisions and actions that shape and guide what
>   an organization is, who it serves, what it does, and why it does it,
>   with a focus on the future. Effective strategic planning articulates
>   not only where an organization is going and the actions needed to make
>   progress, but also how it will know if it is successful.

See: https://balancedscorecard.org/Resources/Strategic-Planning-Basics

Writing something like "Strategic planning: top 50 players in Chess Tournament" would signal to the company that you don't really understand strategic planning in a business context.

If you feel you must mention chess, include it in a "Hobbies" section.

Comment: maybe the recruiters will see me as a potential candidate? I have to be trained anyway

Comment: Self-employed pro poker player should probably list it but at that point it's a job not just a hobby. That should probably be the metric for anything you're thinking of putting on your resume. And while the subtext of your last phrase is clear to me, it should be said that no one except perhaps graduates should ever include a hobby section on their resume.

Comment: "The same would be true for other games - backgammon, bridge, poker, etc." I'd say that poker skills are definitely usable in the real world as being able to read humans is really helpful during negotiations or a any pitch.

Comment: During negotiations, once they figured out what you are doing, it's game over. "He can read what I'm thinking, so I say the price that I want, and I won't budge from it".

Comment: Poker skills can be viewed as much more useful in a professional context, but the gambling/risk taking part may not be to everyone's liking. Treat carefully

Answer (score 3):

Even though I do, in your case I wouldn't. And certainly not in the Skills section.

I've always mentioned my chess skills on my resume, but in the Hobbies section. Feedback was never negative, ranging from one quick slightly intrigued question to a longer discussion with genuine respectful interest. In many people's mind chess is linked to intelligence (it's complete crap obviously, there are dumb people in chess as in any other part of the population), strategic thinking etc. It might also be viewed as a sign of nerdiness (again, cliches die hard) but hey I work in IT so I'm already assumed to have a 50% chance to be an autistic geek :) Seriously it's a good way to tell a bit more about myself in a way that is generally perceived positively, and several times served as an ice-breaker once we were done with the regular hr/technical questions. But it's not intended to prove anything regarding my skillset.

That being said, I would only mention playing chess, not that tournament. To be honest it's just not that impressive. If they show some interest and start discussing your hobby then you can talk about it.

Comment: I have thought that mentioning hobbies is not really beneficial in the cv? But I agree that I can be use for an ice-breaker.

Comment: Can't absolutely say it's beneficial, just that it has served me well. Might be because I'm closer to the beginning of my career (graduated 3 years ago) and since there are less experiences to discuss in an interview those other topics are more important